# DB payload to JSON transformation in mulesoft

Tags: mule, integration, dataweave, mulesoft, raml

[enter image description here][1]my expected output is below,

```
{
  "TicketNo":6255,
  "Name": "Issac",
  "Age": 20,
  "Code": "IND354"
}
```

but I am getting below while transforming the db payload to Json

```
{
  "TicketNo": [
    6255
  ],
  "Name": [
    "Issac"
  ],
  "Age": [
    20
  ],
  "Code": [
    "IND354"
  ]
}
```

attaching my RAML, datatype and values
body:

```
          application/json:
            type: Flight
            examples:
              !include outfile.raml 

#%RAML 1.0 DataType

type: object
properties: 
  TicketNo: integer
  Name: string
  Age: integer
  Code: string

--outfile.raml---
#%RAML 1.0 NamedExample
value:
    TicketNo: 1 
    Name: Issac
    Age: 29
    Code: IND354
```

payload from database
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hm01n.png

Comment: What the input to the transformation, the payload that you are receiving from the database query? What is the RAML for if you are interested in the transformation that happens in your application? Kindly share the complete flow. Please use [code format](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) for code, errors and logs.

Comment: I have attached the payload.

Answer (score 0):

The database query is returning an array of objects. In your example it is returning an array of 1 element. It seems that you are trying to transform the payload directly without considering it is an array, so your transformation returns arrays for each value.

One way to implement the transformation is to select only the first element of the array. This assumes that you only want one object in the response and the query returns at least one object in the response array.

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/java
var firstElement=payload[0]
---
{
    TicketNo: firstElement.TicketNo,
    Name: firstElement.Name,
    Age: firstElement.Age,    
    Code: firstElement.Code
}
```

Comment: How can I transform the payload to JSON array of object?

Comment: Your question expected output -even at the RAML level- was a single object, not an array. Why are you asking now about a different kind of output? Maybe it would be better if you post a new question for that scenario.